# Load Pickle generated with mrjob

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, mrjob

I've built a statistical model (`LogisticRegression` from sklearn) with mrjob and saved it to disk via the `PickleValueProtocol` and piping the output to a file.

Now when loading the pickled file from another python script, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

When saving the model "manually" by adding the appropriate code to my last reducer, I can load the model without any problems.

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me?
Looking at the code of `PickleValueProtocol` makes it even more unclear to me, since this also just returns string in pickle format.

Comment: Can you please provide a short snippet of code detailing how you load the pickled file?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, here's the code: `with open('model.p') as f:
    m = cPickle.load(f)` (works perfectly when saved "manually")